# Hibernate mapping many-to-many different between using xml and annotation

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate, when mapping many-to-many using xml, it's using many-to-many like this:

```
<class name="com.lavin.test.app.dao.hibernate.association.many2many.model.Category2" table="category2" catalog="tt">
    <set name="stocks" table="stock_category" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.lavin.test.app.dao.hibernate.association.many2many.model.Stock2">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```

but, when using annotation, it's using @ManyToOne like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class StockCategoryId3 implements java.io.Serializable {

private Stock3 stock;

private Category3 category;

@ManyToOne
public Stock3 getStock() {
return stock;
}

public void setStock(Stock3 stock) {
this.stock = stock;
}

@ManyToOne
public Category3 getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category3 category) {
this.category = category;
}
}
```

Shouldn't be the same between using xml and annotation when mapping many-to-many relationship? Why these two are different?